# Element not staying within defined area in javascript

Tags: javascript, size, element

I wrote a basic program that moves a button inside a DIV element. The button is not staying within the area I had intended. On the HTML side I have code that defines the DIV with an id = "page". Here is the js code. Why is the button not staying within the DIV element?

```
var buttonState = document.getElementById("clickMe");
var maxWidth = document.getElementById("page");
var maxHeight = document.getElementById("page");
var pageWidth = maxWidth.clientWidth;
var pageHeight = maxHeight.clientHeight;
var screenWidth = 0;
var screenHeight = 0;
function moveButton() {
    "use strict";
    // Find max width and height of screen and set variables to random number within parameters
    screenWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * (pageWidth)) + 1;
    screenHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (pageHeight)) + 1;  
    console.log(screenWidth);
    console.log(screenHeight);
    // Button position
    buttonState.style.left = (screenWidth) + "px";
    buttonState.style.top = (screenHeight) + "px";
    // Button size
    buttonState.style.width = buttonSize + "em";
    buttonState.style.height = buttonSize + "em";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your equations for screenWidth and screenHeight you need to take into account the size of the button.

The div is positioned based on the top left pixel so if you end up with Math.random() returning 1 or something very close to it, the button will fall out of the page unless you subtract the button sizes from the maxes.

```
var buttonWidthPx = buttonState.offsetWidth;
var buttonHeightPx = buttonState.offsetHeight;

screenWidth = Math.floor(Math.random() * (pageWidth - buttonWidthPx)) + 1;
screenHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (pageHeight - buttonHeightPx)) + 1;
```

Also make sure to set the positioning of the button to relative so it positions inside the div and not absolute to the document.

Answer (score 0):

First thought, it is probably more of a css layout issue than javascript or html.

The first clue to this is

```
buttonState.style.left
buttonState.syyle.top
```

If you check the buttonState in Chrome DevTools you might find the layout to be: absolute and that would be one good reason why it does not layout as intended. Another would be if layout is set to static.

Here is a link that gives good depth of information on css layout settings: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

The first thing I would try would be to open DevTools and deselect (remove) all the styles that buttonState has until you find the layout that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact problem that you are facing because you didn't provide any HTML/CSS, but check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tzeoaf7s/) fiddle for a working example.

```
<div id="page">
    <button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
</div>

<button id="move">Move Button</button>
```

---

```
#page {
    width:300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#clickMe {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

---

```
var page = document.getElementById("page");
var pageWidth = page.clientWidth;
var pageHeight = page.clientHeight;
var button = document.getElementById("clickMe");
var buttonWidth = button.clientWidth;
var buttonHeight = button.clientHeight;

function moveButton() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (pageWidth - buttonWidth));
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (pageHeight - buttonHeight));
    button.style.left = x + "px";
    button.style.top = y + "px";
}

document.getElementById("move").onclick = moveButton;
```